# Set margins in maketitle

Tags: titles

Is it possible to change the margins in make title, so they match the margins of the document?

I have created the following modification to the `\maketitle`. I would like everything to align to at the same left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%===============================================
% Title and author
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \vspace*{-\topskip}      % remove the initial space
   \flushleft Incomplete draft. Please do not cite or quote without premission
  \vskip 2em
  {}
  \begingroup\flushleft    % instead of \begin{center}
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \hrule height \z@        % to avoid the insertion of lineskip glue
    {\LARGE \protect\textbf{\@title} \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em

        \@author
        \par}%
    \vskip 1em
    {\normalfont
      Last updated on \@date}
  \par\endgroup            % instead of \end{center}
  \vskip 1.5em             % <--- modify this to adjust the separation
}
\makeatother
%==============================================
\title{Physician Information Acquisition In a Dynamic Setting}
%\email{rud}
\author{
\large {\Large Rud Faden} \\
\textit{\normalfont University of Copenhagen} \\
\textit{{\small \href{mailto:rudfaden@gmail.com}{rudfaden@gmail.com}}}
}
\date{\today} % no date
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\abstract{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
in culpa qui ocia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}



\section{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example isn't compilable. If you complete it you will more likely get an answer as people will see what is going wrong. Moreover `\maketitle` does not change the print space at all. And as far everything is centered, you can not see the margins anyway.

Comment: And also: Be careful with that `\center` in the fifth line. Without an `\endcenter` this example should not even compile. Anyways, it is better to call the `center` environment by saying `\begin{center}` instead of how it is done in your MWE.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean with the margins visible. My problem is that the margins of a long title goes beyond the margins of the body text. But that being said. I will make a MWE

Comment: Ok. I estimated the phrase in the top to be short enough. But, you never know it exactly without a complete example... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the abstract environment instead of `\abstract{...}`like

```
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
in culpa qui ocia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}
```

With this you get,

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. It was driving me crazy.